# Unable to set label justification when label text uses pango markup

Tags: python, pygtk

I want to have a left justified label with some bold text in it, but using the following code (which returns no error) the justification isn't set... Has anyone a clue ? (python2.7, gtk2.24)

```
label=gtk.Label("<b>"+text+"</b>")
label.set_use_markup(True)
label.set_justify(gtk.JUSTIFY_LEFT)
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PyGTK documentation of `gtk.Label.set_justify()` says](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtklabel.html#method-gtklabel--set-justify):

> If you want to set the alignment of the label as a whole, use the `gtk.Misc.set_alignment()` method instead. The `set_justify()` has no effect on labels containing only a single line.

Following the link to [the `gtk.Misc.set_alignment()` documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkmisc.html#method-gtkmisc--set-alignment) shows how to correctly do what you're asking (if I interpreted your question correctly):

```
import gtk

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
text = 'whatever'
label=gtk.Label("<b>"+text+"</b>")
label.set_use_markup(True)
label.set_alignment(0, 0.5)
w.add(label)

w.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

Comment: `.set_alignment(0, 0.5)` - nice

Comment: Nice to find such a simple, clear and perfectly working answer in the jungle of information :)

Comment: The question was for PyGTK but if anyone finds this now and are using the (newer) **PyGObject** bindings it's also possible to use `set_xalign()` on the label. Reference: http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Label.html#Gtk.Label.set_xalign

Answer (score 0):

I am not a GTK developer, but I did some quick searching.  I am wondering if the `gtk.JUSTIFY_LEFT` should be `GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT`.

Reference: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkJustification

```
typedef enum {
  GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT,
  GTK_JUSTIFY_RIGHT,
  GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER,
  GTK_JUSTIFY_FILL
} GtkJustification;
```

Comment: You linked to the C manual, but the question is about the Python bindings. `gtk.JUSTIFY_LEFT` is correct (syntax, at least... it's used wrong in the question though).